# How to create a scorecard for a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to create a scorecard for the values relative to the scorecard (both below).

```
values <- data.frame(A= c(-200,-78,-100,0,-30),
                     B= c(100,0,-101,-199,-300),
                     C= c(-400,400,500,-500,250),
                     D= c(NA,NA,-1000,-1000,-1000),
                     E= c(1000,1000,1,-1000,-2000))

scorecard <- data.frame(Names = c("A","B","C","D","E"), 
                        "Score5" = c(-100,-200,-300,-400,-500), 
                        "Score3" = c(-50,-100,-150,-200,-250), 
                        "Score1" = c(-25,-50,-75,-100,-125))

values
     A    B    C     D     E
1 -200  100 -400    NA  1000
2  -78    0  400    NA  1000
3 -100 -101  500 -1000     1
4    0 -199 -500 -1000 -1000
5  -30 -300  250 -1000 -2000

scorecard
  Names Score5 Score3 Score1
1     A   -100    -50    -25
2     B   -200   -100    -50
3     C   -300   -150    -75
4     D   -400   -200   -100
5     E   -500   -250   -125
```

For my scorecard, if the value:

- is < its respective Score5, it gets awarded 5
- is > its respective Score5 AND < Score3, but closer to Score5 than it is to Score3, it gets awarded 5
- is > its respective Score5 AND < Score3, but closer to Score3 than it is to Score5, it gets awarded 3
- is > its respective Score3 AND < Score1, but closer to Score3 than it is to Score1, it gets awarded 3
- is > its respective Score3 AND < Score1, but closer to Score1 than it is to Score3, it gets awarded 1
- all other values get 0

The desired result is:

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITGvK.png)

I've tried the following - which required the packaged xts: install.packages("xts") but I didn't quite get there.

```
pointsfunction <- function(value)  {
  points <- c()
  for(i in names) {
    index = which(colnames(value)==i)
    data_start <- which(!is.na(value))[1]
    points[1:(data_start -1)] <- NA
    for(a in (data_start):(length(value))) {
      if(value[a] < scorecard[index, 2]) {
        points[a] <- -5
      } else {
        points[a] <- 0
      }
    }
  }
  points <- reclass(points, value)
  return(points)
}

scorecardpoints <- as.data.frame(lapply(values, pointsfunction))
```

I got the following error:

> Error in if (value[a] < scorecard[index, 2]) { : argument is of length
> zero Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)

Any ideas?

Comment: In your last Q you were pretty sure you wanted an `lapply` solution. Are you restricted in using packages? A `dplyr`/`tidyr` or `data.table` solution would be pretty easy here...

Comment: Not at all. I'm still learning R and was comfortable with lapply, but very happy with any working solution.

Comment: I think you want `dplyr` and a `case_when()` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution. We pivot to long format, join to the scorecard, do comparisons, and pivot the result back to wide. I added an ID column, but you can drop it at the end, if you like.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

values %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "Names") %>%
  left_join(scorecard) %>%
  mutate(
    result = case_when(
      value < (Score5 + Score3) / 2 ~ 5,
      value < (Score3 + Score1) / 2 ~ 3,
      value < Score1 ~ 1,
      is.na(value) ~ NA_real_,
      TRUE ~ 0
    )
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = Names, values_from = result)
# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#      id     A     B     C     D     E
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     5     0     5    NA     0
# 2     2     5     0     0    NA     0
# 3     3     5     3     0     5     0
# 4     4     0     5     5     5     5
# 5     5     0     5     0     5     5
```

Comment: When I used this with different data, I received this error:
"Joining, by = "Stocks"
Error: Column 1 must be named.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates 
Error: 1 components of `...` were not used.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `names_to`

Did you misspecify an argument?"

Comment: I've inspected my inputted data and each column has a name.

Comment: Make sure you are creating a unique ID column. Make sure no *other* columns are present before the `pivot_longer`. If you need more help than that, please find a subset of data that illustrates the problem and post it using `dput()`.

Answer (score 0):

The values in your example `values` object is not the same as the values in the `data.frame` you assign to values. E.g. look at the 5th value of `A`.

You could use a base R approach like this:

```
# Look up the scorecard values for a name from the scorecard data.frame
get_scorecard_values <- function(name, card) {
  as.numeric(card[card$Names == name, c(2,3,4)])
}

# translate scorecard values into breakpoints for scoring intervals     
get_breaks <- function(x){
  c((x[1]+x[2])/2, (x[2]+x[3])/2, x[3])
}

# the value to assign to each scoring interval
my_scores <- c(5,3,1,0)

# given a vector of values, assign a score value to each based on
# the interval that it falls into
get_scores <- function(x, intervals, scores) {
  scores[(findInterval(x, get_breaks(intervals)) + 1L)]
}

# go across the list of names of variables of the values object.
# for each name, get the values and corresponding scorecard values
# and calculate the score values.
sapply(
  names(values),
  function(val, values, card, scores) {
    get_scores(
      x = values[[val]],
      intervals = get_scorecard_values(name = val, card = card),
      scores = scores
    )
  }, 
  values = values,
  card = scorecard,
  scores = my_scores
)

     A B C  D E
[1,] 5 0 5 NA 0
[2,] 5 0 0 NA 0
[3,] 5 3 0  5 0
[4,] 0 5 5  5 5
[5,] 0 5 0  5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the dataframe with A5 = -30. Here is a base R solution

```
scoremat <- as.matrix(scorecard[, -1L])
dimnames(scoremat) <- list(scorecard$Names, names(scorecard)[-1L])

vscore <- function(x, nm, scoremat) {
  scores <- c("Score5" = 5, "Score3" = 3, "Score1" = 1)[dimnames(score_mat)[[2L]]]
  conds <- scoremat[rep(nm, length(x)), ]
  i <- as.integer(apply(abs(x - conds), 1L, which.min))
  unname(ifelse(x > conds[, "Score1"] , 0, scores[i]))
}

dscore <- function(df, scoremat) {
  as.data.frame(vapply(
    names(df), 
    function(nm, mat) vscore(df[[nm]], nm, mat), 
    numeric(nrow(df)), 
    scoremat
  ))
}
```

Output

```
> dscore(values, scoremat)
  A B C  D E
1 5 0 5 NA 0
2 5 0 0 NA 0
3 5 3 0  5 0
4 0 5 5  5 5
5 1 5 0  5 5
```

We first create a score matrix as follows

```
> scoremat
  Score5 Score3 Score1
A   -100    -50    -25
B   -200   -100    -50
C   -300   -150    -75
D   -400   -200   -100
E   -500   -250   -125
```

Note that your logic simplifies to

```
for any x in, for example, column A
  if x > -25 (i.e. scoremat["A", "Score1"]) then
    return 0
  else 
   calculate distance = abs(x - values in row A of scoremat)
   return the score where the minimum distance is
```

That's basically how `vscore` works. First match the scores

```
scores <- c("Score5" = 5, "Score3" = 3, "Score1" = 1)[dimnames(score_mat)[[2L]]]
```

Then, match and repeat the row so that the `conds` matrix has the same number of rows as the length of vector `x`.

```
conds <- scoremat[rep(nm, length(x)), ]
```

Next, calculate `abs(x - conds)` and get where the minimum is for each row. For example,

```
let x = values$A

abs (  x   -           conds      )     =         distance       which.min = i
     -200       -100    -50    -25            100    150    175              1
     -150       -100    -50    -25             50    100    125              1
     -100       -100    -50    -25              0     50     75              1
        0       -100    -50    -25            100     50     25              3
      -30       -100    -50    -25             70     20      5              3
              Score5 Score3 Score1         Score5 Score3 Score1
```

Use `as.integer` to convert no match (this happens when there are NA values in x) into `NA` values.

```
i <- as.integer(apply(abs(x - conds), 1L, which.min))
```

Finally, return the results based on the logic shown above

```
unname(ifelse(x > conds[, "Score1"] , 0, scores[i]))
```